# Handling deprecated options in volatile data in comboboxes and similar controls

Tags: c#, vb.net, forms, combobox

I have a rather complicated problem involving comboboxes, listboxes, datagridview-comboboxes, and similar controls.

It's best described with an example of a part of this.

In essence, there is a certain object (let's say it's an order line in an ERP system), which has a field (let's say the part number) which can hold a value which is something that can be selected from another database table (the list of all part numbers).

Now there's a number of part numbers that are no longer made. These are obsolete. Thus, they should no longer be selectable. Of course, there are still old lines which contain this data, so simply removing the obsolete values from the underlying data set would just result in many null-reference errors. Sometimes, I want the box to be disabled entirely when it contains such a value.

Then to make things worse there can be other applications that modify the data. These other applications may not obey the same rules (e.g. they may set a record to a 'disabled' value, again causing null exceptions with the naïve approach).

In the more general case, 'disabled' isn't always directly queryable (e.g. the output of an arbitrary function), but at least cache-able when constructing the selection box.

While I have found it possible to deal with this, my approach has been to figure out the various places where bugs crop up and to manually re-load all the data in the combo-box every time the value changes from the external loss, when it loads, etc. The approach is slightly diffrent each time, and it results in a lot of lines of code for this purpose.

There's got to be a more idiomatic way to approach this problem that is simpler and faster to work with.

I've been thinking about ideas on how to more generically solve the problem, and would like some help for an effective way on how to do this.

For example, an approach could be to;

'Override for example `combobox` to `comboboxEx` which has a class member `deprecatedMember`. This indicates a datasource column. For each option possible, the box would check this column. If it contains a truthy value, then that row is regarded deprecated.

E.g. (VB example);

```
Public Function indexIsDeprecated(ByVal i As Integer) As Boolean
    If Me.DeprecatedMember Is Nothing Then 
        Return False
    Else
        If Me.Items(i)(Me.DeprecatedMember) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

The `comboboxEx` also should contain a boolean `disableDeprecated` property, which, when true, causes it to become disabled whenever its value changes to or is a deprecated value, and vice versa enabled when its value changes to a non-deprecated value.

A deprecated row is supposed have at least these properties:

1. Only visible if the combobox is set to its value, or the underlying bound data has the value (so it can be re-selected when the user changes it).
2. While invisible, the user is unable to select it even with the keyboard.
3. However, the code using the `comboboxEx` should still be able to access these 'hidden' rows.
4. Able to support being set to a currently 'invisible' value. That value should be set as the current value and made visible. This may happen through its data-binding (i.e. another application changes the underlying value in the database, and the data is reloaded by e.g. a refresh of the form afterwards)
5. If the `disableDeprecated` option is true: When the user changes the box' value to one enabled option from another, the underlying datasource value needs to be checked; if it's now a disabled value, then the user change should be ignored and the value from the underlying datasource used instead.

(This list may not have been exhaustive. )

Is this a good approach, or would you suggest going about the problem via a different route?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is the following:

1. My data source for the dropdown returns a list of items and each item has a property "active" (set to true or false).
2. For dropdowns that should only contain the active items, I return the model containing a list of active items. If the selected item is one of the non-active items, then this item is also included in the list to avoid nulls.
3. For dropdowns that should contain all items (active and inactive) all items are returned in the model for that dropdown, so all values can be chosen.